# Tagging multiple questions at the same time?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is it possible to tag multiple questions at the same time? If not, should this feature be added?

I've wanted to do this several times when I do a search for a topic, and many of the matches do not have a certain important tag, but should.

For example, a search for "boost asio -[boost-asio]" returns a lot of questions that are extremely specific (not just perpherially related) to boost::asio, and should have the [boost-asio] tag. Adding the tag to each of them individually is possible, but it would be less daunting if there was a way to mark the appropriate questions from the search results and tag them all at once. (Even if this is a bad example for some reason, hopefully you get the idea).

I'm anticipating arguments that this *shouldn't* be possible because it would make it too easy for people to mistag things in batch. In that case, I'd argue that it similarly also makes it easier for people to *fix* things in batch, and should only be available for folks with high enough privileges that we should trust them anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I like the idea, I think there are a few problems that make it impractical.

- What do you do with questions that already have five tags?
- How do you handle the homepage flooding that would result from this type of mass editing?
- How can you determine, without looking at the question, that the tag you think fits is really what the question is about?
- How do you go about fixing a massive retag that's erroneous? (Massive rage-quit damage possible, unless there's some tight controls and roll-back possibilities.)

In your specific case for [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio), a tag merge first would clear things up a tiny bit ([asio](/questions/tagged/asio) refers to the same thing).

Also looking at the first fifteen results for the search you suggest:

- Some don't contain [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) either which could be an issue (or not)
- Ten already have [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) and [asio](/questions/tagged/asio)

The next pages start getting irrelevant. Around page 7 you get questions not really related to asio.

Even with a "finer" search like `+boost +asio -[boost-asio] -[asio] in:question`, you still get https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374147/what-is-boost-missing <sup>*</sup> for instance. That should not get [boost-asio](/questions/tagged/boost-asio)'d. So you should at least glance at each question anyway.

So, if you're on a retag mission, I do believe advertising it here if there's just too much stuff for one person is the best way.

<sub>* Funny this is still open</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the good analysis of impacts if this feature were to be added. I still think this feature would be useful in some cases, but you've at least convinced me that I can live without it. =)